# php5-fpm: bash script to check config before restart

Tags: php, bash, scripting, php-fpm

I write a script to create new vhost on Nginx. That script creates Ningx vhost config file, vhost user and dirs, php-fpm pool file.

At the end of the script, I would like to check if config is ok before restart php-fpm. For Apache, I do `apachectl graceful`, but is it possible to do something similar with `php5-fpm -t`?

Answer (score 22):

From the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/php5-fpm.8.html):

> ```
>   --test
>   -t             Test FPM configuration file and  exit  If  called  twice
>                  (-tt), the configuration is dumped before exiting.
> ```

`php5-fpm -t` should exit with code 0 if the config is valid, and a non-zero exit code if not. Your script should do something like this then:

```bash
if ! php5-fpm -t; then
    echo "php5-fpm configuration is invalid"
    exit 1
fi
```

However, I made some changes to my configuration which weren't picked up as invalid, so YMMV.

Comment: php7 names are a bit different, e.g. `php-fpm7.1`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40891683/151503